# Gnuplot: change font size for plot with labels

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to be able to control the font size for the labels produced by

```
plot file u 1:2:(sprintf("%4.3f", $1)) with labels offset char 0,2 t ""
```

but have not found a way yet. Let me add that I use the epslatex terminal.

Comment: From `help labels`: `plot 'cities.dat' using 5:4:1 with labels font "Times,8"`

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect. Note that I use the epslatex terminal.

Comment: In the case of the latex terminals the font choice and size are under the control of LaTeX rather than gnuplot's internal enhanced text processing. You would have to format the label as a TeX command.

Comment: `plot file u 1:2:(sprintf('{\\tiny %4.3f}', $1)) with labels notitle`

Comment: Note that the format uses single quotes so only two backslashes are needed.  If for some reason you need to place it in double quotes an extra layer of escape processing is needed, thus four backslashes

Comment: @EthanMerritt wonderful. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of the latex terminals the font choice and size are under the control of LaTeX rather than gnuplot's internal enhanced text processing. You would have to format the label as a TeX command.

```
plot file u 1:2:(sprintf('{\\tiny %4.3f}', $1)) with labels notitle
```

Note that the number of escaped backslashes depends on whether you place the format in single or double quotes.